# Are Failed Firebase Push Notification Chargeable?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently, I am developing a Flutter mobile app and implementing firebase push notifications in the app. Then I was wondering whether these notifications are charged in the case they fail to be delivered. For example, in the case the user deleted the app then his Firebase token is no longer valid, and therefore sending push notifications to that invalid token will fail. In this case, will I be charged for this failed notification? Thanks in advance.

I did some research about this but could not get a clear answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "charged"? Firebase Cloud Messaging is free to use, without any charges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then I was wondering whether these notifications are charged in case they fail to be delivered.

You won't be charged with anything, no matter if a notification arrives to the user or fails for any reason.

> For example, in the case the user deleted the app then his Firebase token is no longer valid, and therefore sending push notifications to that invalid token will fail. In this case, will I be charged for this failed notification?

No, you won't. As @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned in his comment, the [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) service is [free of charge](https://firebase.google.com/pricing). There is nothing that you should pay.

Comment: Is it not charged after going over 2M push notifications in a month

Comment: No, there is no fee, even if you get over 2M notifications a month. If you want, you can check the [best practices when sending FCM messages at scale](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FY9_5H39sYQ).

Comment: Hey Adrien. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using cloud messaging, you can detect invalid token responses and safely delete your record of this token, since it will never again be valid.

Here is the complete documentation to do so:
[Detect invalid token responses from the FCM backend](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-tokens#detect-invalid-token-responses-from-the-fcm-backend)

Comment: Will be great if you share an example, for this answer to by complete.